# Getting a strange error when attempting to subtract the minimum of a column from the entire column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a weird error when I attempt to subtract the min of a column in pandas from the column itself.

My code looks like this:

```
self.portfolio.number = self.portfolio.number - self.portfolio.number.min()
```

The dataframe itself is member data of a class - not sure if this is relevant to the issue (assuming it isn't).

The error is as follows:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

I've seen a couple of similar errors posted on stack overflow. I have checked the column isn't duplicated and it isn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `self.portfolio['number'].sub(self.portfolio['number'].min())`

Comment: Thanks @ksooklall, that worked. Do you know why my original line didn't work? works perfectly fine elsewhere in my code

Comment: Apologies I was mistaken this actually didn't work.

Comment: is `self` your pandas.DataFrame, or is this in some other class declaration? And what is the column name, because there is no such thing as a `number` attribute for a Series, which is really the only way I can make sense of your code. In this case it's better to post a small sample of your data.

Comment: 'self' is the pointer to the class itself; the above line of code is situated within the function of a class. The dataframe 'portfolio' is a member datum of the class. So self.portfolio is the dataframe and number is the column name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Had to change my code to:

```
self.portfolio.loc[:, 'number'] = self.portfolio['number'].sub(self.portfolio['number'].min())
```

This works but I'm not sure why. If someone could enlighten me I would hugely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If this answer seems a little off, it'd be helpful if you could provide a little more info about the data structure you have going on.

However, I believe something along these lines will work for you.

```
import pandas as pd

data =  {'number': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73,4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['number'] - df['number'].min()
```